# Problema em função de enfileirar

Tags: c++

Estou tentando criar uma fila com structs, mas não tá funcionando os trecho de atribuição nas linhas 17/18, não tô encontrando o erro. A lógica que estou utilizando está correta?

> ```
> error: request for member 'nome' in 'FilaAluno', which is of pointer type 'aluno' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
>
> FilaAluno[fimfila].nome = FilaAluno.nome;
> ```

Eu estou usando o Atom com o Myngw.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max_fila 2
 struct aluno {
  char nome [100];
  int cod;
  int turma;
} ;

bool enfileirar(aluno FilaAluno[], int &i, int &fimfila){
  if (fimfila == max_fila){
    std::cout << "fila cheia" << '\n';
    return false;
  }
  else{
    FilaAluno[fimfila].nome = FilaAluno[i].nome; //problema
    FilaAluno[fimfila].cod = FilaAluno[i].cod; //problema
    FilaAluno[fimfila].turma = FilaAluno[i].turma;
    fimfila++;
  }
  return true;

}
int main(){
  aluno FilaAluno [max_fila]; //fila
  int inifila = 0;
  int fimfila = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < max_fila; i++) {
    /* code */

    std::cout << "Codigo:" << '\n';
    std::cin >> FilaAluno[i].cod;
    std::cout << "Nome:" << '\n';
    std::cin >> FilaAluno[i].nome;
    std::cout << "Turma:" << '\n';
    std::cin >> FilaAluno[i].turma;

    if(enfileirar (FilaAluno, i, fimfila)){
      std::cout << "Item adicionado com sucesso!" << '\n';
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Como assim "não tá funcionado"? Além disso, marque com um comentário as linhas com problema, pra evitar que as pessoas tenham que contar as linhas do código.

Comment: @pabloalmeida, acabei de corrigir. Não está funcionando pois está dando um erro de atribuição, diz que é invalida. Não sei também se minha lógica está correta, pois o material da faculdade não está muito bom.

Comment: Obrigado, Tiago, mas seria bom você colocar o texto exato do erro.

Comment: @pabloalmeida, coloquei a mensagem apresentada.

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem de erro que você colocou não bate com o texto: não existe um comando

```
FilaAluno[fimfila].nome = FilaAluno.nome;
```

nas linhas de código que você mostrou...

Mas, existe uma erro nesta linha

```
FilaAluno[fimfila].nome = FilaAluno[i].nome; //problema
```

que deve ser

```
memcpy(FilaAluno[fimfila].nome, FilaAluno[i].nome, 100);
```

mas para isso funcionar você precisa inserir no início do programa esta linha:

```
#include <cstring>
```